# How do I insert a website inside my html web page

Tags: html

How do I insert a youtube web page into my HTML web page using I frame,
and please I need a code snippet that I can run to see how it looks like.

Comment: Follow the steps in this link https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: "please I need a code snippet that I can run to see how it looks like." Sorry, but that is not how StackOverflow works. Please read the [help] and take the [tour] to find how to ask a better question. On the Youtube video you want to embed, click "share" then "embed" to get the embed code for that video.

Comment: [More information on iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Read comments below asking to insert google search as an iframe. Don't think thats possible. Google checks the origin of the document and doesnt let you do it on an iframe (last time I checked)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to start a video on the web page.

Below can work out.

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1">
</iframe>

Comment: what would you want to do with Google?

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.setPlaybackRate(2);
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: thank you but I just need an I frame with src of google can you do that without involving any javascript

Comment: what u mean by google src ? did u mean the site adress www.google.com?

Comment: if u meant publishing your site on google go through this:https://support.google.com/sites/answer/6372880?hl=en